# AS3 code with an interface has suddenly started giving "Call to a possibly undefined method"

Tags: actionscript-3

GameWorld.as, Line 96   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method initialize.

I am adding a controller to my GameWorld that implements IController:

```
addController(new BackgroundController(this));

public function addController(controller:IController):void
{
    controller.initialize();
    controllers.push(controller);
}

public interface IController 
{
    function initialize():void;         //setup the controller
    function getType():String;          //define the controller by a type string
    function update():void;             //perform update actions
    function destroy():void;            //cleanup the controller
}
```

initialize is a method from IController but is now undefined suddenly

I am getting no syntax errors and cant seem to revert my code to a working state.

What could be causing this?

Here is the BackgroundController:

```
package controller 
{
    import Entity;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class BackgroundController implements IController
    {
        private var world:GameWorld;
        private var images:Vector.<Bitmap>;
        private var bgImage:Sprite;

        public function BackgroundController(world:GameWorld)
        {
            this.world = world;
        }

        public function initialize():void
        {
            bgImage = new Sprite();
            images = new Vector.<Bitmap>();

            var ypos:int = 0;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            {
                var tempBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new grasstile(0, 0));
                images.push(tempBmp);
                bgImage.addChild(tempBmp);
                tempBmp.y = ypos;
                ypos += 500;
            }

            GameWorld.lowerLayer.addChild(bgImage);
        }
        public function update():void 
        {
            //update the background tiles
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            {
                images[i].y -= world.gameSpeed;
                if (images[i].y < -500 )
                {
                    images[i].y += 1500;
                }
            }
        }

        public function getType():String
        {
            return "Background";
        }

        public function destroy():void 
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: RESOLVED: everything I tried did nothing to allow my interface to be reached until I added an empty main class and added my GameWorld to it.  I don't quite understand why this worked, but great success!

Answer (score 1):

**Some global checks**

- Are you using runtime shared assets, multiple files? Make sure you've build them all.
- Make sure there are no other runtime/build errors
- In FDT (which editor do you use?) there is a feature called 'reset the MXML compiler and force full build'. That clears the cache and forces to do a complete new build instead of an incremental build.
- In Flashdevelop you have to use tools > flash tools > rebuild class path
- In the Flash IDE you could clear the ASO files(CS5-) / clear publish cache (CS6).
- Restart/kill the editors + related processes to make sure there are no weird cache conflicts and all syntax checking is up to date.

**Code checks**

```
// make sure it has implemented the IController
trace("controller is IController: "  + (controller is IController) );
```

and..

```
// detect what kind of class it really is. Goto that class, check the interface.
trace("controller is : "  + getQualifiedClassName(controller) );
```

Also make sure there are no other `IController` interfaces, or check all the import statements, so your sure everywhere the right interface is used.

Comment: +1 "Also make sure there are no other IController interfaces, or check all the import statements, so your sure everywhere the right interface is used." - seems the most likely culprit, if the error is occurring on previously functional code.

Comment: i am using flashdevelop to write and Flash IDE to compile, I cleared ASO and rebuilt class path and restarted my computer.  It now seems to be going back and forth between that error and another in my WorldConfig class Attempted access of inaccessible method addController through a reference with static type GameWorld.

Comment: and it gives me Call to a possibly undefined method getQualifiedClassName when I try to trace it

Answer (score 1):

Found myself in the same situation.

Discovered that the problem was due to a name-clashing issue between the package and the defined variable.

So, in your case, just changing

```
public function addController(controller:IController):void
{
    controller.initialize();
    controllers.push(controller);
}
```

to

```
public function addController(controllerImpl:IController):void
{
    controllerImpl.initialize();
    controllers.push(controllerImpl);
}
```

should have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

An interface just defines rules for a class, in this case stating that any class implementing `IController` must contain definitions for those four methods.  Do you actually have an initialize method defined in your controller class?

Comment: BackgroundController has all 4 defined, as do all of my other classes implementing IController, what I don't understand is how this could have happened after ive been using it for hours